# How to use PlaceAutoCompleteFragment widget in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I am using `PlaceAutoCompleteFragment` inside a `Fragment`. First time when Fragment(App fragment in which `PlaceAutoCompleteFragment` is placed) opens it works fine like a charm.

But, then second time I hit button to open Fragment it crashes with below error. It works only a single time.

FATAL EXCEPTION:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error
>   inflating class fragment Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #64:
>   Duplicate id 0x7f0d0094, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with
>   another fragment for
>   com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment

This is how I am using this,for Search location

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parkingview_fragment, container, false);

            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_parkingview);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

          // For Search location
          PlaceAutocompleteFragment  autocompleteFragment = null;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

                    autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_fragment_parkingview);
            }

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);
        autocompleteFragment.setHint("Search a Location");
//        autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW);

        return view;

    }
```

XML:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_fragment_parkingview"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Jordan's answer is correct.  You should select it as such.

Answer (score 4):

Declare your fragment Dynamically it will solve the issue.

`<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />`

And Update your fragment onCreateView

`SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = new SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, autocompleteFragment);
        ft.commit();`

Comment: Its working fine but  fragment.getView() returning null in that case  how we can access clear_button

Comment: @ramkrishnakushwaha You can use a globalLayoutListener, set up from within onViewCreated(): https://gist.github.com/gavingt/b1e80ba9e0da3e59a95c045a0e058928

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused because you haven't removed yet the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment instance created before at some point.

Careful guys! If you use the method posted by Jordon, it will work, but the fragment's views (the input edittext, and the clearbutton for example) won't be accesible because the fragment's views aren't created yet...the correct answer is REMOVE the instance of the fragment putted in the xml file, programmatically, overwriting the onDestroyView method on the Fragment containing the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {    
if (autocompleteFragment != null) {
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
   fragmentTransaction.remove(autocompleteFragment).commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
}
super.onDestroyView();    
}
```

This way, anytime you recreate your Fragment it won't have an instance of the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment already created. Happy Coding!

Comment: i have this error: incompatible types: PlaceAutocompleteFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Answer (score 2):

I was using-

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/plain_border"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
```

inside my fragment layout file and initializing it using-

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment locationAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
        getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.location_autocomplete_fragment);
```

I switched to-

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/plain_border"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
```

and initialisation by-

```
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment locationAutocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.location_autocomplete_fragment);
```